# Server successfully votes for a different map but loads the same one

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, hosting

On my CSGO server, I have it so that there are two maps to vote for at the end of the game. When the vote goes, it says it will load the other map but instead picks the same one. Why is that?

Comment: Most likely a bug in CS:GO, or maybe the map being chosen is the same one!

Comment: @Beminfire It is not the same one. I have made sure.

Comment: Is your map list set up properly to include the new map?

Comment: @dly Yes it is.

Comment: Are you using SourceMod? If so what plugins are in use as well?